# Another way to use downsampling in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

let’s look at some one-minute data:

```
In [513]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=12, freq='T')
In [514]: ts = Series(np.arange(12), index=rng)
In [515]: ts
Out[515]:
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0
2000-01-01 00:01:00      1
2000-01-01 00:02:00      2
2000-01-01 00:03:00      3
2000-01-01 00:04:00      4
2000-01-01 00:05:00      5
2000-01-01 00:06:00      6
2000-01-01 00:07:00      7
2000-01-01 00:08:00      8
2000-01-01 00:09:00      9
2000-01-01 00:10:00      10
2000-01-01 00:11:00      11
Freq: T
```

Suppose you wanted to aggregate this data into five-minute chunks or bars by taking
the sum of each group:

```
In [516]: ts.resample('5min', how='sum')
Out[516]:
2000-01-01 00:00:00 0
2000-01-01 00:05:00 15
2000-01-01 00:10:00 40
2000-01-01 00:15:00 11
Freq: 5T
```

However I don't want to use the `resample` method and still want the same input-output. How can I use `group_by` or `reindex` or any of such other methods?

Comment: Is there any particular feature of `resample` which you don't like? Or is this an homework-like problem?

Comment: you can use time-groupers with groupby

Comment: You may think of it as a homework-like problem.

Comment: @JohnE can you detail me on how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [pd.Grouper](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) this way:

```
 In [78]: ts.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min', closed='right')).sum()
Out [78]:
1999-12-31 23:55:00     0
2000-01-01 00:00:00    15
2000-01-01 00:05:00    40
2000-01-01 00:10:00    11
Freq: 5T, dtype: int64
```

The `closed='right'` ensures that the output is exactly the same.

---

However, if your aim is to do more custom grouping, you can use `.groupby` with your own vector:

```
 In [78]: buckets = (ts.index - ts.index[0]) / pd.Timedelta('5min')
 In [79]: grp = ts.groupby(np.ceil(buckets.values))

 In [80]: grp.sum()
Out[80]:
0     0
1    15
2    40
3    11
dtype: int64
```

The output is not exactly the same, but the method is more flexible (e.g. can create uneven buckets).